# Posting return value of a database query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am trying to figure out how to get the return value to post. My code is as follows

```
    <?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","db");

$lname=$_POST['lname'];


$query= "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE lname = '".$lname."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);     
if (!$result) {
  printf("Query failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
  exit;
}      

return $result;
?>
```

I am pretty new to php, but what i am doing is getting a name posted to the php file, it then goes to the database, finds all values that have the last name inputted, and then i want it to return the values and then print them

Comment: Research SQL Injection before allowing this code near a production machine.  This is dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [mysqli_result::fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","db");

$lname=$_POST['lname'];


$query= "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE lname = '".$lname."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);     
if (!$result) {
  printf("Query failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
  exit;
}      
while ($contact = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $contact['name']."<br>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with `mysqli` format, but that does not look parameterized and does look awfully tasty to a would-be SQL Injector.

Comment: It is not parameterized and is open to SQL injection in its current form. That's up to the question asker to address. Since it wasn't what they were asking about I didn't turn this into a lesson in good SQL practices. There's enough of them both in this website and on the Interwebs.

Comment: When i try that i get this message       Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_assoc() in /home/camelarc/public_html/searchform.php on line 14

Comment: Have mysql return a count of affected rows and verify there are actual results